# How to get simple product id of configurable product on Product details page

Tags: magento2, product-view

In product details page when user choose  like color and size it returns simple product id of that[image]

Comment: You can use this link magento1. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28881/get-simple-product-id-from-configurable-product-selection

Comment: @payal When user select the size and color, it returns product id of that

Comment: from which, using js or php want to get to id?

Comment: i want alert message to show its simple product id

Comment: Did you solve it? I am also looking for something similar.

Comment: me too, did anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

I have select box at attribute of configurable product. This is what i have done to get simple product id. Put following code in your configurable product phtml file.

```
 require(["jquery"], function(jQuery) {
      jQuery(".product-options-wrapper select[id^='attribute']").last().on('change', function() {
          setTimeout(function (){
            simpleId=jQuery("input[name=selected_configurable_option]").val();
            alert(simpleId);
          }, 500); 
      });
}); // Required
```

If you have configurable swatch than it will required minor change in above code.Hope it will help someone.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
foreach($collection as $_product) {
    $_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds($_product);
    $getChildId = array();
    foreach ($_children as $child){
        $getChildId[] = $child->getID();
    }
    print_r($getChildId);
}
```

Comment: thanks for replay but i want somthing more,when i click size of any value with respective color it return only that simple product id .

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get id of selected simple product in configurable product on client side you can do it by below way.

Here is simple function how to achieve that with no code modification, new templates or even modules.
Just one Javascript file and layout update.

```
Product.Config.prototype.getIdOfSelectedProduct = function()
{
     var existingProducts = new Object();

     for(var i=this.settings.length-1;i>=0;i--)
     {
         var selected = this.settings[i].options[this.settings[i].selectedIndex];
         if(selected.config)
         {
            for(var iproducts=0;iproducts<selected.config.products.length;iproducts++)
            {
                var usedAsKey = selected.config.products[iproducts]+"";
                if(existingProducts[usedAsKey]==undefined)
                {
                    existingProducts[usedAsKey]=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    existingProducts[usedAsKey]=existingProducts[usedAsKey]+1;
                }
             }
         }
     }

     for (var keyValue in existingProducts)
     {
        for ( var keyValueInner in existingProducts)
         {
            if(Number(existingProducts[keyValueInner])<Number(existingProducts[keyValue]))
            {
                delete existingProducts[keyValueInner];
            }
         }
     }

     var sizeOfExistingProducts=0;
     var currentSimpleProductId = "";
     for ( var keyValue in existingProducts)
     {
        currentSimpleProductId = keyValue;
        sizeOfExistingProducts=sizeOfExistingProducts+1
     }

     if(sizeOfExistingProducts==1)
     {
         alert("Selected product is: "+currentSimpleProductId)
     }
}
```

Comment: You should update your current answer.