# How to get the ids of the attribute or simple products on a configurable product detail page?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I am repeating the question which is already asked by [someone](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135509/how-to-get-simple-product-id-of-configurable-product-on-product-details-page) , but its not answered.
I want to get the simple product id when size or color is clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do it same as magento 1,

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

    //get option label based on option id

    $optionId = 10;

$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
 if ($attr->usesSource()) {
       $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
 }
//get option text ex. Red

//get option id based on option label

$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
 if ($attr->usesSource()) {
       $option_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId("Red");
 }
```

//get option id ex. 10

Thanks.