# How to get Current Child id from Configrable Product in Magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I have configure product with 3 colors.How to get **Current Child product_id** from **Configurable Product** in Magento2?

If anyone knows please explain me

Comment: On which page? there might be possible that configurable product has more than one child

Comment: Sorry ,don't understood your question , what i means by Current Child product id?

Comment: In product page...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "Current child product_id" A configurable product *could* have more than 1 child

```
$children = array();
foreach($collection as $_product) {
        $productName = $_product->getName());
        $_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
        foreach ($_children as $child){
            $children[] = $child->getID());
        }
    }
```

And `$children` would contain all the child ids in an array. Maybe this gives you enough to go on to do what you are trying to achieve?

To get the Simple product based on the selected configurable options you will want to take a look at this answer by obscure: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/28912/2671

Comment: EX:Configurable product have 3 colors.If i have select red color. how to get that red color product id in product view page

Comment: In that case @MahalakshmiM it looks like you need something like this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/28912/2671